# How to automatically rerun failed TestNG tests on Jenkins and update the final results to pass if retries passes?

Tags: testng, jenkins

How to automatically rerun failed TestNG tests on Jenkins and update the final results to pass if retries passes?

Description:
I have two tests that ran. Test1 passed, but Test2 failed then on retry it passed.

Actual Results:
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0.

Expected Results;
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

or

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1 (Skipped for retry tests)

```
    public class TestRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private static int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 1; 
    //Only works for value of 1; Anything more than that causes 
    infinite retries for the same test even when it passes.

    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RETRY_COUNT);

    public boolean isRetryAvailable() {
        return (count.intValue() > 0);
    }

    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        boolean retry = false;
        if (isRetryAvailable()) {
            Reporter.log("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", " + (MAX_RETRY_COUNT - count.intValue() + 1) + " out of " + MAX_RETRY_COUNT, true);
            retry = true;
            count.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return retry;
    }
}

  public class TestListenerSupport extends TestListenerAdapter {
  TestUtilities testUtil = new TestUtilities();

@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result){
    //Handle events before test start
    //Obtain specific annotation info from test methods
    Stable stable = 
  result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
  .getAnnotation(Stable.class);
   Maturing maturing = 
  result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
  .getAnnotation(Maturing.class);
   Preflight preFlight = 
   result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
   .getAnnotation(Preflight.class);
      if (stable != null){
           Reporter.log("Annotation is set to STABLE! for '" + 
    result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "'.", true);
      }
      if (maturing != null){
           Reporter.log("Annotation is set to MATURING! for '" + 
    result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "'.", true);
     }
      if (preFlight != null){
           Reporter.log("Annotation is set to PREFLIGHT! for '" + 
    result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "'.", true);
    }
}


  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result){

      if (result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer() != null) {
            TestRetry retryAnalyzer = 
     (TestRetry)result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer();

            if(retryAnalyzer.isRetryAvailable()) {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
            } else {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
            }

            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
        }
}

@Override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result){

    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped invoked! " + result.getThrowable().toString(),true);
    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped Exception Message: " + result.getThrowable().getMessage(),true);
    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped Exception Cause: " + result.getThrowable().getCause(),true);
    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped Exception StackTrace: " + result.getThrowable().getStackTrace(), true);
    AppiumDriver driver = getDriverInstance(result);
    if(driver!=null){
        TestUtilities testUtil = new TestUtilities();
        try {
            testUtil.getScreenShot(driver, result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "_Skipped");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Reporter.log("Killing appium driver instance",true);
        driver.quit();
    }
    else
        Reporter.log("onTestSkipped - null driver detected", true);
}

@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result){
    Map map = new HashMap();
    //get the testcase IDs from input xml file used for creating a test run in TestRail
    Map<String,String> test_case_id = result.getMethod().getXmlTest().getAllParameters();
    String test_name = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    testUtil.writeResult("1", test_case_id.get(test_name));

}
```

Comment: I am not sure this is a good practice in testing. If your test does not pass from the first time then there is some issue in your app-under-test or with environment. This should not be addressed on test level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted my code with what Nick mentioned in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622365/testng-how-to-only-output-one-pass-fail-result-when-test-is-rerun

and it worked.

Thanks.

```
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
private int count = 0;
private int maxCount = 2;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
if (!result.isSuccess()) {
  if (count < maxCount) {
    count++;
    result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
    String message = Thread.currentThread().getName() +
    ": Error in " + result.getName() + " Retrying "
        + (maxCount + 1 - count) + " more times";
    System.out.println(message);
    Reporter.log(message);
    return true;
  } else {
    result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
  }
}
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer? Then others know that this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG provides the [`IRetryAnalyzer`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IRetryAnalyzer.html) interface, which you can implement like this:

```
public class MyRetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private AtomicInteger retries = new AtomicInteger(3);

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        return retries.getAndDecrement() > 0;
    }

}
```

Afterwards, you can use it as follows:

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = MyRetryAnalyzer.class)
public void myTest(){
    // ...
}
```

However, flaky tests are evil—and so is the excessive use of retry rules. Have a look at this related question:

[How to deal with flaky tests that have intermittent failures?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28204/how-to-deal-with-flaky-tests-that-have-intermittent-failures/)

Comment: I did something similiar, but the retries that are passed are still counting towards a build failure and the jenkins marked it red instead of green. I would like the retries to be considered pass and the build to pass and to have jenkins mark it green. Let me post my code above in original post. Thanks.